# Power strip cord length

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm trying to avoid putting a new electrical outlet in. I need to be able to directly plug some devices into the strip which directly plugs into the wall. Is there a power strip greater than 25' that exists. Or is there any alternate solution anyone can think of? I must avoid using a extension cord to plug in the power strip.

Comment: What does an extension chord sound like?

Comment: @brhans: It has lots of harmonics.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: do they get lower in frequency if I plug more stuff in?

Comment: im forming a band

Comment: This may be on topic in DIY, but it's pretty much a shopping question.

Comment: Also,  there are 3 outlet 50 feet extension cords. Check home improvement stores

Comment: Local regulations may make these illegal. Why must you avoid an extension cord? You could add a cord and join the two inside an enclosure that was sealed shut | You could buy a cord separately and remove the cord from the power strip and terminate the new cord in its place. If these ideas are not acceptable then telling us why may help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A extension cord is the obvious simple answer.

In case you actually have a legitimate aversion to a extension cord in this application (hard to imagine), you'll either have to find a power strip with a long cord or lengthen a existing one yourself.  Power strips with long cords seem to be rare, probably because many consumers by on price and they can be cheaper with short cords, and people can add their own extension cord.

Lengthening a cord is fairly simple if you know how to solder and make everything safe afterwards.  **However**, if you have to ask here how to do that, then you shouldn't do that.  The safety and fire risks are such that if aren't sure you know how to do this, get someone that is sure to do it or use a extension cord.  I'm not going to go into the details here because this is the kind of thing not appropriate to learn from the other end of the internet.  Learn from someone that actually knows how to do it properly.

Even if you did a good job of lengthening the cord, it likely won't be legally acceptable or it can be used as a excuse by the insurance company not to pay if the building burns down.

Comment: the extension cord into the power strip was considered "illegal" by the fire marshal that visited my company. This is why I was looking for alternatives. Lengthening the cord may be illegal like you said. Sounds like I need a long power strip or just have to install an outlet from above.

Comment: If I remember correctly, plugging a power strip into the end of an extension cord violates some obscure paragraph of the NEC unless the manufacturer of one or the other of them specifically says its ok to do so.

Comment: correct, that's why I am looking for lengthening alternatives

Comment: (Apparently I can not post my own answer?? I don't understand this website. Oh well.) Do a Google search and see the first result: custom length power strip .... I've had good luck with the 5th result stayonline.com for high quality custom-made UPS power distribution cables.